# Using app.set vs app.value in Express

Tags: node.js, express

In my app.js file, I use `app.set(valName, value)` to pass several config values to my routes.
I then pass the app to my routes: `app.use('/', require('./routes/index')(app))`;
I can then easily use `app.get(valName)` to retrieve the values in the routes.

My question is: wouldn't it be easier to just use `app.valName = value;` and then just access `app.valName` in the route?
Do I have to use the `.set` and `.get`? Or will this be violating something?

Comment: Only difference I can think of is if something needs to listen for the get/set events of a certain property on `app`. But I'm interested to hear from someone who is more familiar with express.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to use the `.set` and `.get`? Or will this be violating something?

Do you *have* to? No. Should you? Yes!

By setting your application properties directly to the `app` object (e.g. `app.valName = value;`), you may be overwriting properties that Express has initialized for internal use.

You can see from [Express's source code](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L33) that Express applications create the following properties in their `init` function:

```
this._baseRoutes = {};
this.cache = {};
this.settings = {};
this.engines = {};
this.defaultConfiguration();
```

And even more properties are set after the [`defaultConfiguration` function](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L47) is executed. This means that if you want to have a property named `cache`, `settings`, or `engines`, just to name a few, you will be stepping on Express's toes and will probably cause something to go wrong when your application is running.

You can see from the [source of `app.set`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L308) that application settings are sorted in a settings object, not directly in the application object. This is to prevent what I just described above: conflicts with internal property names.